# Can I use common cathode PLCC 4 led to replace common anode PLCC 4 led?

Tags: led, surface-mount

I need to replace the led on my car gear shifter.
From my research, I understand that I need to get the common anode PLCC 4 3528 led with green color.
However, the seller sent me the common cathode one.

The question is can I use the common cathode led to replace the original common anode led?

My idea is to put 1 anode and 1 cathode in correct orientation and left the 2 anode unsoldered.

The circuit board is look like this
[image: Gear Shifter board]

Thanks in advance

Comment: in the PLC3528 datasheet the two diodes are completely separated and there is no common anode unless it is connected on the board. what is the code of the received one.

Comment: @PaulGhobril the seller sent me Wurth with part number 150141GS73140. The datasheet can be seen here: https://www.we-online.de/katalog/datasheet/150141GS73140.pdf

Comment: So the one you received has only one green LED and the one mounted on your board has 2 LEDs (Bi-color). You may use one LED instead of two for each. Is this what you want?